# mousePressEvent() method is not working as expected when calling setPos() method

Tags: qt, position, mouseevent, qgraphicsitem

I have a class MenuItem which inherits from QGraphicsItem and reimplemented boundingRect(), shape(), paint(), outlineRect():

```
MenuItem::MenuItem(const QString& qsText, qreal qrYPos)
{
    m_qsText = qsText;
    m_BackgroundColor = Qt::white;
    m_OutlineColor = Qt::darkBlue;
    m_TextColor = Qt::darkGreen;
    qDebug() << pos();
    setPos(mapToParent(200,200));  //<-- when calling this method, mousePressEvent()
                                   // behaves not as expected
    qDebug() << pos(); 
}

QRectF MenuItem::boundingRect() const
{
    const int iMargin = 1;
    return outlineRect().adjusted(-iMargin, -iMargin, +iMargin, +iMargin);

}

QPainterPath MenuItem::shape() const
{
    QRectF rect = outlineRect();

    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(rect);

    return path;
}

void MenuItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QPen pen(m_OutlineColor);

    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->setBrush(m_BackgroundColor);

    QRectF rect = outlineRect();
    painter->drawRect(rect);

    painter->setPen(m_TextColor);
    painter->drawText(rect, Qt::AlignCenter, m_qsText);
}

void MenuItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Item Mouse Pressed";
}

QString MenuItem::getText() const
{
    return m_qsText;
}

QRectF MenuItem::outlineRect() const
{
    const int iPadding = 8;
    QFontMetricsF metrics = QFontMetricsF(QApplication::font());
    QRectF rect = metrics.boundingRect(m_qsText);
    rect.adjust(-iPadding, -iPadding, +iPadding, +iPadding);
    rect.translate(-rect.center());
    return rect;
}
```

In another class, called Menu which inherits from QGraphicsScene, I added one instance of MenuItem:

```
Menu::Menu()
    : QGraphicsScene()
{
    setSceneRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

    m_miNewGame = new MenuItem("New Game", 300);
    this->addItem(m_miNewGame);
    //m_miNewGame->setPos(200,200);
}
```

The Menu class reimplements mousePressEvent

```
void Menu::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    //qDebug() << "Menu Mouse Pressed";
    MenuItem *gi = dynamic_cast<MenuItem*>(itemAt(event->pos(), QTransform()));
    if (gi)
        qDebug() << gi->getText();
    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event); // this forwards the event to the item
    if (itemAt(event->pos(), QTransform()))
    {
        qDebug() << "You Pressed an Item";

    }
}
```

If I use setPos() method inside the MenuItem constructor the MenuItem gets positioned right but inside the Menu::mousePressEvent() method, MenuItem* returned from itemAt() is always NULL.

Omitting the setPos() method, the MenuItem stays in the top left corner (0,0) of the scene and mousePressEvents are handled as expected: returning the MenuItems Text with the getText() method.

Why is the MenuItem* NULL when calling setPos()?
Do I have to reimplement setPos() or what am I doing wrong?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MenuItem()` constructor you use `mapToParent`. But your item doesn't have any parent item. So using `mapToParent` is pointless, it's equivalent to `mapToScene` in this case. And since your item's initial position is (0, 0) and no transformation has been applied, `mapToScene` will return its argument's value without changes. So it's equivalent to `setPos(200, 200)`. It seems strange to use the result of `mapToParent` or `mapToScene` in `setPos`. I don't understand what you were trying to do.

`QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent::pos` returns coordinates of the event in *target item*'s coordinates. Since you're using it in `QGraphicsScene::keyPressEvent`, the event has not been propagated to any item, and `pos()` always returns (0, 0). The documentation isn't clear about it, but I've checked it.

If you didn't use `setPos`, your item's position will be (0, 0) and `itemAt(0, 0)` will find your item (regardless of the point the user have actually clicked). But if you did use `setPos`, `itemAt(0, 0)` returns 0 because there is no item at this point. If you replace `event->pos()` with `event->scenePos()`, it will work correct.

However, it's unusual to reimplement `QGraphicsScene::keyPressEvent` to catch clicking on item. You should reimplement `QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent` instead. It will be called only if the item has been clicked, and you don't have to check event's coordinates to determine that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Riateche! You are right, the 'mapToParent()' method makes no sense, it was just a try.

Comment: When reimplementing `QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent`, how is it possible to recognize which MenuItem e.g. "New Game" inside the Menu class has been clicked? Would you emit a signal insid the `QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent` or is there a better solution?

Comment: I think emitting some custom `clicked()` signal is OK. But note that you need to derive from both `QGraphicsItem` and `QObject` if you want to use signals. You can also add `Menu::itemClicked(MenuItem*)` method and call it from `MenuItem::mousePressEvent`.